# check element of tuple at certain position - shortcut?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I am trying to find tuples in a list with a certain symbol at the 2nd position. The list looks something like this:

```
list = [ (0, "a", 1), (1, "b", 2), (2, "c", 3)]
```

I can obviously find all the tuples with e.g. a "c" by running the following code:

```
for item in list:
    if item[1] == "c":
        return item
```

I was just wondering if I could combine line1 and line2 of the above given code to do something like

```
for (numb1, symbol=="c", numb2) in list:
    return (numb1, symbol, numb2)
```

Does anyone know if there is a shortcut for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Also list comprehension is not an option..

Comment: curious as to why list comprehension isn't an option. I don't think theres a huge performance difference in using `filter` as opposed to a list comprehension.

Comment: You shouldn't use "list" to name your lists because it is the name of built-in function

Comment: Also, your "obvious" way to find all the tuples with a "c" does not work. It finds only the first tuple with a "c".

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge There is a performance difference. But it is in favor of list comprehensions... And I am also quite curious why list comprehensions are not possible here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` with a quick lambda.

```
def get_cs(ts):
    return filter(lambda t: t[1] == 'c', ts)
```

or, since you seem to be only returning the *first* value found:

```
def get_cs(ts):
    return next(filter(lambda t: t[1] == 'c', ts), None)
```

Comment: The first parameter in `filter` should be the lambda

Comment: @damores whoops, it's been too long!

Comment: If you don't want to use a function call, you can do list(filter(lambda t:  t[1] == 'c', ts))

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [item for item in list if item[1]=="c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
input = [(0, "a", 1), (1, "b", 2), (2, "c", 3)]
output = [item for item in input if item[1] == "c"]
```

I would advise you not to use `list` as a variable name, as it would overwrite the `list()` function

EDIT: I have just read that list comprehension is not an option so @adam-smith answer would do it. Performance wise, list comprehension are implemented as map-filter functions. Also, they are more readable that filter functions, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print [a for a in alist if a[1]=='c']
```

output:

```
[(2, 'c', 3)]
```

Comment: OP has stated that list comprehension is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Since list comprehensions seem not to be an option and you seem only interested in the *first* matching tuple, how about a generator expression:

```
next(t for t in ts if t[1] == 'c', None)
```